# Почему мне выдает Attempt to invoke virtual method com.example.cinema.responses.TVShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails()' on a null object reference?

Tags: java, android, rest

Четвертый день не могу понять почему мне пишет

> Attempt to invoke virtual method com.example.cinema.responses.TVShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails()' on a null object reference

если у меня вроде все правильно написано.

Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста.
Через `REST-API` я вытягиваю список фильмов на сайте, после этого я хочу получить более детальную информацию про нужный мне фильм. Из списка фильмов нажимаю на любой фильм, и у меня вылетает.

Вот логи

```
    02-12 21:34:17.993 25684-25684/com.example.cinema E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping 
    layout
    02-12 21:34:17.996 25684-25684/com.example.cinema E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping 
    layout
    02-12 21:34:18.079 25684-25684/com.example.cinema E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cinema, PID: 25684
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'com.example.cinema.models.TVShowDetails 
    com.example.cinema.responses.TVShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails()' on a null object reference
        at 
    com.example.cinema.DetailsActivity.lambda$getTVShowDetails$0$DetailsActivity(DetailsActivity.java:43)
        at com.example.cinema.-$$Lambda$DetailsActivity$GnroofsMecGfgW6cU0TaT06vJcI.onChanged(lambda)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at com.example.cinema.repositories.TVShowDetailsRepository$1.onFailure (TVShowDetailsRepository.java:34)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onFailure$1$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$G9BY9eQQk64nBfFjfIpx-YzJzUo.run(lambda)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5620)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
```

Вот класс, который отвечает за вывод детальной информации

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityDetailsBinding activityDetailsBinding;
private TVShowDetailsViewModel tvShowDetailsViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityDetailsBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_details);

    doInitialization();
}
private void doInitialization(){
    tvShowDetailsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TVShowDetailsViewModel.class);
    getTVShowDetails();
}

private void getTVShowDetails(){
    activityDetailsBinding.setIsLoading(true);

    String tvShowId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("id",-1));
    tvShowDetailsViewModel.getTvShowDetails(tvShowId).observe(
            this,tvShowDetailsResponse -> {
                activityDetailsBinding.setIsLoading(false);
                if (tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails() != null){
                    if(tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails().getPictures() != null){
                          loadImageSlider(tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails().getPictures());
                    }
                }
            }
    ); 
}
private void loadImageSlider(String[] sliderImages){
    activityDetailsBinding.sliderViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); //проверить
    activityDetailsBinding.sliderViewPager2.setAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapter(sliderImages));
    activityDetailsBinding.sliderViewPager2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activityDetailsBinding.viewFadingEdge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Вот главный класс, с которого я посылаю `Intent` для определения `id` записи

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TVShowListener {
@Override
public void onTVShowClicked(TVShow tvShow) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id",tvShow.getId());
    intent.putExtra("name",tvShow.getName());
    intent.putExtra("startDate",tvShow.getStartDate());
    intent.putExtra("country", tvShow.getCountry());
    intent.putExtra("network",tvShow.getNetwork());
    intent.putExtra("status",tvShow.getStatus());
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Вот класс Респонс

```
public class TVShowDetailsResponse {

@SerializedName("tvShow")
private TVShowDetails tvShowDetails;

public TVShowDetails getTvShowDetails() {
    return tvShowDetails;
}
}
```

Вот интерфейс Апи Сервис

```
public interface ApiService {
// https://www.episodate.com/api/most-popular?page=1
@GET("most-popular")
Call<TVShowsResponse> getMostPopular(@Query("page") int page);

// /api/show-details?q=:show
@GET("show-details")
Call<TVShowDetailsResponse> getTvShowDetails(@Query("q")String tvShowId);

}
```

Вот класс под `ViewModel`

```
public class TVShowDetailsViewModel extends ViewModel {
private TVShowDetailsRepository tvShowDetailsRepository;

public TVShowDetailsViewModel(){
   tvShowDetailsRepository = new TVShowDetailsRepository();
}

public LiveData<TVShowDetailsResponse> getTvShowDetails(String tvShowId) {
   return tvShowDetailsRepository.getTvShowDetails(tvShowId);
}
}
```

И вот класс под репозиторий

```
public class TVShowDetailsRepository {

private ApiService apiService;

public TVShowDetailsRepository (){
    apiService = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);
}

public LiveData<TVShowDetailsResponse> getTvShowDetails(String tvShowId){
    MutableLiveData<TVShowDetailsResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiService.getTvShowDetails(tvShowId).enqueue(new Callback<TVShowDetailsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<TVShowDetailsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<TVShowDetailsResponse> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body() );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<TVShowDetailsResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            data.setValue(null);
        }
    });

    return data;
}
}
```

Я уже столько раз изучал это все... Я не вижу тут ошибки, должно все правильно работать... Может, кто-то из опытных сможет помочь.

Comment: В `onFailure` вы передаёте значение `null` - значит при любой попытке использовать `TVShowDetailsResponse` вы должны его проверять на `null`. А в самом `onFailure` нужно хотя бы при отладке печатать ошибку в лог. Ну и желательно обработать её по по уму - юзер ведь должен знать почему данные не отображаются, ждать ему, интернет подключить или что делать... Да и в `onResponse` нужно проверять ответ сервера, так как в `onFailure` передаются только ошибки со стороны клиента.

Comment: Ну так я же и проверяю это значение на null.Вот к примеру при вызове метода слайдера в детейлс активити я сначала проверяю на null (tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails() != null), а после этого еще проверяю на null есть ли картинки для него (tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails().getPictures() != null).С отладкой согласен, нужно это дописать, но опять же это не решит проблемы...я реально не могу понять что не так в коде, почему он мне говорит что там значение пустое...

Comment: Но саму переменную `tvShowDetailsResponse == null ?` вы не проверяете, а она `null`

Comment: Не совсем понял...вы предлагаете перед тем как проверить tvShowDetailsResponse.getTvShowDetails() != null проверять еще tvShowDetailsResponse != null ?Так?или я что-то туплю..

Comment: Именно. И в `onFailure` добавьте `t.printStsckTrace()`, иначе так и не узнаете почему ответ от сервера не пришёл или не конвертиуется.